# From inside a yarn workspace subpackage, run a root-level script

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm wondering: if your terminal's current working directory is inside a yarn workspace, is there a way to run a yarn script that's defined at the project root without changing the current directory to be outside of a workspace?

For instance, you can run a command for a particular workspace by running `yarn workspace workspace-name script-name` but is it possible to use that `yarn workspace` command to target not a subpackage, but the root package itself?

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't find a way to do it with `yarn workspace`, but you can do it by specifying the current working directory (`cwd`) when running the root command. Assuming you're running your command from `~/packages/subpackage`, you'll need to go back two times with `../..`:

```
yarn --cwd="../.." my-root-script
```

Answer (score 2):

Scripts that contain a `:` in their name can be run from anywhere!

For example, your root script called `"root:something"` can be called from within any workspace by running `yarn root:something`.

Note that this even works if the `:` script is not a root script, but a workspace script. See [yarn docs](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/run#details).

Comment: Superb. This works.

Comment: This is specific for yarn 2

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add, that with yarn berry, you can use the `-T` option on the run command.

```
yarn run -T my-top-level-script
```